# Ignorar los ultimos caracteres de una cadena en PHP

Tags: php, substr

Buen día, estoy haciendo el INSERT en una tabla de la base de datos en dos campos , uno que es el nombre de usuario y otro es la contraseña.

De momento ambos campos tienen el mismo contenido, por ejemplo

USUARIO          | CONTRASEÑA
correo@correo.com  correo@correo.com

Esto debido a que estoy mandando el mismo parámetro para ambos campos.

Quisiera que en el nombre de usuario ignorara a partir de @correo.com para que quedara el nombre solo en correo.

Tengo entendido que esto se logra con la función substr no tengo conocimiento de como se podría ignorar la parte de la cadena que deseo eliminar.

Espero puedan ayudarme, saludos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes probar con esto:

```
<?php
$email = explode("@","nombre@correo.com"); 
echo $email[0]; // Imprime "nombre"
echo $email[1]; // Imprime "correo.com" 
?>
```

Espero sea la respuesta que buscas.

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias maneras de hacer esto:

### Usando [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) <sup>1</sup>

```
$email="correo@correo.com";
$user = strstr($email, '@', true); // Para el usuario, a partir de PHP 5.3.0
$domain = strstr($email, '@'); //Para el dominio
```

### Usando [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)

```
$email="correo@correo.com";
$user = substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
```

### Usando [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)

```
$email="correo@correo.com";
$partes = explode("@", $email);
$user = $partes[0];
```

También se puede usando REGex, pero no vale la pena recurrir a este método para algo tan simple.

---

<sup>1</sup> El parámetro `true`, con el cual se obtendría el nombre de usuario es compatible solamente con versiones de PHP superiores a la versión `5.3.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Es relativamente sencillo amigo lo unico que tienes que hacer es como dices usar substr y es de la siguiente forma.

```
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 8); //Devuelve 'abcdef'
```

En este codigo como puedes observar puedes tomar cierta parte de la cadena de texto como se muestra, pero en tu caso no te serviria ya que necesitas es devolver todo lo que este antes del simbolo @ asi que usarias algo como lo siguiente.

NOTA: Puedes usar el substr pero me parece un poco mas elegante la forma que te planteo a continuacion.

```
before ('@', 'biohazard@online.ge'); //Devuelve biohazard

before ($this, $inthat) { 
    return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $this)); 
};
```

En este caso devolverias todo lo que este antes del simbolo que le indiques y creo que eso es lo que estas buscando. Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Existe la función `before` en PHP?

Comment: @KacosPro si mira aqui te dejo la estructura. function before ($this, $inthat)
    {
        return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $this));
    };

Comment: Deberías agregar eso a tu respuesta, pensé que era una función nativa de PHP, la busqué como loco jaja

Comment: @KacosPro Tienes razón, despues de todo hay que dejar la respuesta completa xD

Answer (score 0):

Podría solucionarla de esta manera

```
$usuario = 'juan@correo.com';

$pos = strpos($usuario, '@'); //Busca el indice donde está la arroba

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "No se encontró la @";
} else {
    $usuarioSinCorreo=substr($usuario, 0, $pos-1 ); //Substrae desde el inicio de la cadena hasta la posición donde se encuentra la arroba
    echo $usuarioSinCorreo;
}
```